# Oscillator's frequency way off LC prediction

Tags: oscillator, passive-networks, tank

I tried to make the simple Robinson oscillator given in the pictures below using cross-coupled NPN transitors attached to an LC tank circuit.  The part that I have used is M2N4401.

The issues I find are:

1. When I look at the inductor in parallel with the NanoVNA there is only a large resonance at 270 MHz. The LC tank should have a resonance at 1/(2*pi*sqrt(0.7μH*30pF)) = 34.7 MHz
2. The circuit itself resonates at 25 MHz, with very little variation with respect to the different capacitance.

Is it possible that there is some parasitic capacitance in the breadboard or PCB that is changing the frequency the oscillator resonates at? How can I get the system to resonate at the expected frequency?

[image: marginal oscillator]

[image: circuit on bread board]

[image: Network Analyzer result]

Comment: Breadboards have tiny capacitors all over the place; some combination of which is causing your results. Look up "Manhattan Style" prototyping for RF and try that for something closer to expected results

Comment: Wires are too long ... and no decoupling capacitor ...

Comment: 2SC3355 is a "GHz" transistor ... At what frequency should the circuit works ?

Comment: The 50 ohm load of the NanoVNA will destroy the Q of your LC as a parallel tank. No resonance. Might try measuring it in series.

Comment: The [2SC3355](https://www.alphacron.de/download/hardware/2SC3355.pdf) pinout does not match with your breadboard image. Please specify what part you have used.

Comment: @JohnDoty For that matter -- granted with a partial view of the display it's anyone's guess -- but, it looks like a notch, and 30pF + 11nH would at least be in the right ballpark for series resonance of the capacitor + lead length (the inductor is essentially out of circuit at this frequency).

Comment: @Antonio51 The frequency it is supposed to operate at is 50 MHz.

Comment: @TimWilliams The part that I have used is M2N4401

Comment: @TimWilliams At 50 MHz the RF wavelength is 6 meters. What length would keep the inductor in the circuit?

Comment: TY, @YousifAlniemi. Will look at the Manhattan Style this evening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For folks who have difficulty getting an oscillator to actually *oscillate*, this one is tempting...because it is difficult for it to *not oscillate*.
Having 100% feedback between the two cross-coupled transistors makes it a sure-fire oscillator.

> Is it possible that there is some parasitic capacitance in the
> breadboard or PCB that is changing the frequency the oscillator
> resonates at?

Yes, those breadboards can have roughly 5pf between adjacent strips, making them less attractive for use in high-impedance circuits, or for high-frequency circuits.
But breadboard capacitance is likely not the major offender for shifting resonance. Since transistors were chosen having very high GBW-product, transistor capacitances are small. These too will bring down resonance slightly.
This resonator is heavily-loaded by the transistors, which are operating non-linearly at very low voltage near saturation. So the DC operating point influences frequency far more than it should.

> How can I get the system to resonate at the expected frequency?

One wishes to couple the resonating tank more loosely to the transistor(s) that sustain oscillation, so that loading is decreased. Tank current flowing back-and-forth between resonator L & C should be far higher than current drawn into the sustaining transistor(s). But be aware that attempting this moves this oscillator toward non-oscillation.

- To maintain symmetry, DC should really be fed into the resonating inductor mid-way (centre-tap). Collector are now at a voltage higher than base. These two inductors can merge into one, with coupling between two halves.
- Resonator energy is lightly coupled to transistor base with a small coupling capacitor - here 2.7 pf. This capacitor should tend to shift frequency downward a bit because it adds to the 30pf tank capacitor.
- Transistor base is DC-biased with a large value resistor. Its voltage will of course be near 0.7V. Transistor collector is now at a significantly-higher voltage - swinging around +3V, allowing some linear swinging room.

[image: push-pull oscillator schematic]

This oscillator barely oscillates in LTspice, since those 2.7pf coupling capacitors barely provide enough feedback. If built, it would likely fail to oscillate because of additional losses not included in the LTspice simulation. Increasing these 2.7pf capacitors should enhance chances of oscillation.
With C6 (30pf) removed, oscillations occur at 113.79 MHz.

LTspice oscillations occur at **33.14 MHz.**
Calculating resonance (L=0.7uH, C=30pf)... **34.73 MHz**
Calculating resonance (L=0.7uH, C=30pf + 1.35pf)... **33.974 MHz**

---

BTW NanoVNA source impedance is very close to 50 ohms as @JohnDoty pointed out in comments. It will seriously-load a parallel resonant LC circuit. You'd be better off probing L and C separately, preferably near 34 Mhz.

Another approach would probe a series connection of L & C instead of parallel with NanoVNA. Impedance goes to a minimum at resonance. Resonance may be fairly sharp, so VNA frequency steps should be small, or you'll miss resonance.

Comment: Ty, @glen_geek, I think you've come close to the heart of my problems with this project: http://jabolatorium.com/Projects/Esr_simple/esr_simple.html. Because of strong coupling of the transistors I don't see the RF being absorbed by the sample in the tank circuit. However, because inductor has to go into a magnetic field, I can't centre-tap. Is there anything else I can do to improve decoupling?

Comment: instead of a center tap inductor, one could distribute DC to both ends of it using two matched resistors. center tapping is easy for a trace inductor, but for a coil might not be always available/easy.

Comment: thanks, @tobalt, but could you give a little more detail since it is not entirely clear to me what you mean. What are the resistors matched to? Where exactly are they supposed to be placed?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, @tobalt, but I take from your words that instead of center tapping the coil, center tap to the point between 2 resistors of equal value that are both in parallel to the coil.

Comment: Am unsure what property of OP's *marginal oscillator* is attractive for his application. Perhaps my modified version is less-appropriate - the two certainly have different properties. For the original Robinson osc: substituting VHF transistors for those 2N4401 may help move frequency up. Those 2N4401 are large-area, with a fair amount of internal capacitance, which may account for some of your difficulty in calculating frequency.

Comment: Thanks again @glen_geek. One thing I noticed was the the 2N4401 is now obsolete and so I am forced to switch to something else, either the 2N3904 or the VHF ones you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we can start by figuring out how much we need to account for.

The measured frequency is 25MHz, 72% of the expected 34.7MHz.  F goes as \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{C}}\$, so C goes as the inverse square of F, or 193% of expected.  93% of 30pF is an additional 27.8pF we have to account for.  Assuming of course, it's at resonance and everything -- and we'll be making some approximations depending on other circuit and component details, probing, etc., but this will be in the ballpark of what we're looking for.

The [2N4401](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/2n4401-d.pdf) has about 30pF input and 6.5pF output capacitance (maybe more like 7-10pF at the low V<sub>CE</sub> this circuit will run at).  Your layout appears to skip every other row in the breadboard, a forward-thinking step -- typical capacitance between rows is 4pF, so we can expect 2pF here.

Note that B-E and E-B act in series between the two transistors, so these are effectively halved, or 15pF; B-C and C-B are in parallel, effectively doubling them, or 14pF.  The breadboard contributes 2pF C-C, and 2pF C-E and E-C in series, or about 3pF total C-C equivalent.

This gives us a total 32pF, which is right in the ballpark of what we're looking for, so that seems satisfactory.  It's a bit of an overestimate really, but that may be down to measurement error of the inductance, additional stray capacitance due to the breadboard backplane (being metal), device variations, or just differences in the assumptions used here.

I'm actually a bit surprised it's not more, because Miller effect might be expected to cause much more apparent input capacitance at the transistors.  It seems this is swamped by other effects.

To reach 50MHz, reduce L, reduce C some, and use a much smaller transistor, such as 2N3904 (4, 8 pF), or MMBTH10 (~1pF Ccb, undocumented Ceb).

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams. By switching to 2N3904 transistors, 5 pF transisitors and a 0.3 μH inductor, I was able to get 47 MHz. This is roughly what one would expect factoring in stray capacitances you mentioned. However,  I am curious to know why the originators of this project don't have the same amount of difficulty.: jabolatorium.com/Projects/Esr_simple/esr_simple.html

Comment: @luiz_iniciante The original 2SC3355 is a *very* high frequency transistor, even less capacitance than Tim's MMBTH10 suggestion. If 2N3904 moved you up in frequency, then using much higher frequency transistors should get you higher frequency. I'd wire this simple circuit in air using direct point-to-point short soldered connections. Air wiring minimizes stray capacitance.